# Citing with a shortened version of the author name

Tags: bibtex, citing

I have a paper where some of my citations are organizations with unwieldy, long names. e.g. I have a bibtex entry:

```
@unpublished{CAQH2013,
  title={2013 U.S. Healthcare Efficiency Index: Electronic Administrative Transaction Adoption and Savings},
  author="{Council for Affordable Quality Healthcare}",
  year={2014},
}
```

If I use \citet{CQH2013}, I get

`Council for Affordable Quality Healthcare (2014)`

as the output. But I instead want something like

`CAQH (2014)`

as the output. How can I do this automatically?

I researched and one suggestion is to use \defcitealias. But the problem is that my current bbl style has \citet as above, but \citep as

`(Council for Affordable Quality Healthcare 2014)`

and so if I were to put in \citepalias(CAQH) I would get

`(CAQH (2014))`

which is not preferable. Is there a way to make an "author-specific alias" of sorts?

Comment: Some styles support a "short author" field that can hold abbreviations, but if that is available depends on your style, which you haven't shared. There is no general solution that will work the same across all BibTeX styles. If you want more specific help for your problem, please share a small example document that reproduces your current bibliography and citation setup with as little excess code as possible.