# How to reference and cite corporate authors with acronymised names?

Tags: bibtex, cross-referencing, author, back-referencing, harvard-style

I'm referencing the following tech report by the "New South Wales Environmental Protection Agency" which is a long corporate author name that I'd like to acronymise in my text. The suitable acronym which people use in conversation and online is "NSW EPA" which I'd like to show when I cite (using \cite{}). Is there a way I can do this to my bibtex file so that the citation reads the acronym and the reference list has the full and acronymised name as the author?

The reference is as follows:

```
@techreport{FlyAshausstandards2009,
  title       = {Environment Compliance: Report Coal Ash Dams and Emplacements},
  author      = {{NSW Environmental Protection Agency}},
  institution = {NSW Environmental Protection Agency},
  address     = {},
  number      = {},
  year        = {2009},
  month       = {August},
  url         = {https://www.epa.nsw.gov.au/-/media/F296D19215D348A8BC16DEB4D2021A52.ashx},
}
```

Thanks! Note also that I'm using Overleaf if that matters and I'm using the apa (apacite) referencing style for BibTeX. More specifically, I'm using the Curtin University PhD thesis template as seen in https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/curtin-university-phd-thesis-template-for-astronomy/ggxgtpqnydcx.

Comment: This will depend on your style and possibly also on your bibliography/citation package. See also my comment under https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/650873/35864. Please tell us more about your bibliography/citation setup.

Comment: Which citation management package, if any, do you employ?

Comment: @Mico, I'm not sure I don't think I use any. I'm using the Curtin Uni PhD thesis template as seen in https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/curtin-university-phd-thesis-template-for-astronomy/ggxgtpqnydcx. I will edit my question with this information.

Comment: Apologies, I use the apa (apacite) style for BibTeX